# How do I save input values inside shinyglide?

Tags: r, shiny, glidejs

I have this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)

ui <- fixedPage(
  
  titlePanel("shinyglide modal example"),
  
  actionButton(
    inputId = "actionlatex1",
    label = "click"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("mean", "Mean", value = 0),
      numericInput("sd", "Standard deviation", value = 1, min = 0),
      numericInput("n", "n", value = 100, min = 1),
      p(
        tags$a(
          href = "https://github.com/juba/shinyglide/blob/master/inst/examples/03_modal/app.R",
          "Source code on GitHub"
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    modal_controls <- glideControls(
      list(
        prevButton(),
        firstButton(
          class = "btn btn-danger",
          `data-dismiss` = "modal",
          "No, thanks!"
        )
      ),
      list(
        nextButton(),
        lastButton(
          class = "btn btn-success",
          `id` = "save",
          `data-dismiss` = "modal",
          "Done"
        )
      )
    )
  
  observeEvent(input$actionlatex1, {
    
    showModal(
      
      modalDialog(
        
        title = "Startup assistant",
        easyClose = FALSE,
        footer = NULL,
        
        glide(
          
          custom_controls = modal_controls,
          
          screen(
            next_label = 'Yes, please ! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            p("Let's initialize some values, would you ?")
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("First, please select a mean value"),
            numericInput("mean_modal", "Mean", value = 0)
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("Next, please select a standard deviation value"),
            numericInput("sd_modal", "Standard deviation", value = 1, min = 0)
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("Thanks, we're all set !")
          )
        
        )
          
      )
      
    )
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(req(input$n), req(input$mean), req(input$sd)),
         main = "Such wow",
         xlab = "Wonderful x values",
         ylab = "Incredible frequencies")
  })
  
  observe({
    updateNumericInput(session, "mean_modal", value = input$mean)
    updateNumericInput(session, "sd_modal", value = input$sd)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to store the values of the inputs (mean, sd and n) so that when I reopen and close the modal the values remain there when I modify them.

I tried using a javascript but it got confusing, so I decided to remove it from the current code. I also tried to create a modal with jquery, but I didn't succeed either. I need to save the R inputs when closing and reopening the modal.

Comment: Your code is not working (`mainPanel()` is missing).

Comment: Okay, could you also clarify the question. Do you want to somehow save the values of the `numericInput` or the ones given in the modal? Currently nothing happens inside the app if the user has clicked through the modal and set some values.

Comment: I just need to store the values in the modals after closing and reopening them as often as these events occur. I don't need to use them for anything afterwards, I just need to store them in there. I've only provided this example because it's close to the package maintainer code, that's why.

Comment: So if e.g. the user chooses `mean = 2` in the modal, finishes the modal and opens it again, then the 2 should be the displayed input value. Is this the requirement?

Comment: I would just like to keep the values in the inputs (inside the modal) when closing and reopening the modals. What matters to me is that the values remain inside the modal even after reopening and closing. For example, if in "mean" I type 1999, I need the value 1999 to remain in the input inside the modal even after closing and reopening it several times. No matter what the values are outside the modal, I need to store the values of the inputs inside the modal: I need to store the values of the inputs but inside the modal after reopening and closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValues` to initialize the inputs once the modal is shown:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)

ui <- fixedPage(
  
  titlePanel("shinyglide modal example"),
  
  actionButton(
    inputId = "actionlatex1",
    label = "click"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("mean", "Mean", value = 0),
      numericInput("sd", "Standard deviation", value = 1, min = 0),
      numericInput("n", "n", value = 100, min = 1),
      p(
        tags$a(
          href = "https://github.com/juba/shinyglide/blob/master/inst/examples/03_modal/app.R",
          "Source code on GitHub"
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  modal_controls <- glideControls(
    list(
      prevButton(),
      firstButton(
        class = "btn btn-danger",
        `data-dismiss` = "modal",
        "No, thanks!"
      )
    ),
    list(
      nextButton(),
      lastButton(
        class = "btn btn-success",
        `id` = "save",
        `data-dismiss` = "modal",
        "Done"
      )
    )
  )
  
  modal_inputs <- reactiveValues(mean_modal = 0L, sd_modal = 1L)
  
  observe({
      lapply(names(modal_inputs), function(x){
        if(!is.null(input[[x]])){
          modal_inputs[[x]] <- input[[x]]
        }
      })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$actionlatex1, {
    
    showModal(
      
      modalDialog(
        
        title = "Startup assistant",
        easyClose = FALSE,
        footer = NULL,
        
        glide(
          
          custom_controls = modal_controls,
          
          screen(
            next_label = 'Yes, please ! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            p("Let's initialize some values, would you ?")
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("First, please select a mean value"),
            numericInput("mean_modal", "Mean", value = modal_inputs$mean_modal)
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("Next, please select a standard deviation value"),
            numericInput("sd_modal", "Standard deviation", value = modal_inputs$sd_modal, min = 0)
          ),
          
          screen(
            p("Thanks, we're all set !")
          )
          
        )
        
      )
      
    )
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(req(input$n), req(input$mean), req(input$sd)),
         main = "Such wow",
         xlab = "Wonderful x values",
         ylab = "Incredible frequencies")
  })
  
  observe({
    updateNumericInput(session, "mean_modal", value = input$mean)
    updateNumericInput(session, "sd_modal", value = input$sd)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```